# How to explain visually and in a mathematically simple manner why the moment of inertia of a system is minimum at its center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I've been solving different problems related with finding the moment of inertia in a set of different particles, and ojects of known rotational inertias. Let's say spheres, cylinders, rings, rods and so on.

To put it in perspective, let's assume that we have a cube with four point masses in each corner and I want to find the moment of inertia of the whole system when the moment is at minimum.

I'm assuming that when the degree of rotation (i'm not sure if the term is correct, please indicate me if this is wrong) is the least then the contribution of the rotational inertia is not affected by any additional radius as when there is some offset from the center of mass of the object.

Typically when I want to know what will be the rotational inertia of a system I would use the principle of superposition of rotational inertia for the system and then Steiner's theorem to find the moment of inertia for an axis paralell to that point.

Hence this formula is expressed as:

$I_{p}=I_{o}+mr^2$

where $I_{p}$ is the rotational inertia of the system about that point and $I_{o}$ the moment of inertia where axis of rotation for that object is in its center. Since there isn't any additional radius to add, the whole expression would be reduced to

$I_{p}=I_{o}$

But I'm not sure if this is a valid conclusion.

There exists a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247020/meaning-of-parallel-axis-theorem-why-is-the-moment-of-inertia-minimum-if-the-ax) which has attended this topic but in a mathematical aspect but it is lacking of a justification in the sense of how to visually explain this fact.

Therefore, does it exist a video or an animation or an experiment on how can this be proved? I don't know if at this point I'm explaining my major confusion. Can all of this be proved in layman terms?.

The existing mathematical proofs for this are a bit too sophisticated for my current knowledge of mathematics, but does there exist an introductory calculus explanation for this behavior? Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you not think your argument is not valid?

Comment: @AaronStevens Because I feel it is lacking of some formality or to my understanding is not fully developed. Maybe I am just overthinking too much?. Hence why I posted the question, because a mathematical proof so far for me is not filling the conceptual question which I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of parallel axis theorem: why is the moment of inertia minimum if the axis passes through the CM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247020/meaning-of-parallel-axis-theorem-why-is-the-moment-of-inertia-minimum-if-the-ax) See also [Moment Of Inertia About Centre of Mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171836)

Comment: @sammygerbil My question was not originally meant solely to ask a justification mathematically but also visually and such is not explained neither mentioned in the link you have provided.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell What kind of visual answer are you expecting? SMcGrew's answer is simple and requires no mathematics.

Comment: @sammygerbil The purpose of this question was to have some sort of **diagram** or **animation** to see how or why the moment of inertia is minimum at its center of mass. The mathematical justification is okay but it does not fill the gap this question was meant to. Can rotational inertia of an object be seen spinning and this spinning be reduced or increased when the axis is at its center? The latter was part of the intended purpose. I dont know if this was makes clearer.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Yes I think I understand what you are asking but I have no idea how it could be done, except by animating SMGrew's answer. That would seem to be rather a tall order, for something which is very easy to imagine. Users provide answers here voluntarily, to help learners understand, not to entertain. Sometimes a diagram makes a big difference. In this case I don't see how it could help. If you are still having difficulty understanding any of the answers given you can post a comment asking for clarification. Your feedback might suggest a suitable visual aid.

Comment: @sammygerbil I disagree, because people's imagination is not the same. The way how I see things might not be the same as yours. Regarding it to be a tall order. I don't think it is such a big deal, there are lots of packages which can do that, such as [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/). Certainly the pedagogic aspect of it outweighs any indication of entertainment as you mentioned. I wish I could add such animation, but would my rendering be what is it intended from the answer?. I don't know. Therefore I believe should be left openened so anyone with experience

Comment: @sammygerbil on these packages could add it as an answer. Sure I will, but I still believe my answer has not been fulfilled.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You are welcome to post a question on Physics Meta asking for this question to be reopened, giving your reasons. Asking for someone to animate something which can easily be imagined is asking too much IMO. Asking someone to invent a new way of explaining the concept visually is also asking too much. And unless you are willing to put in the effort to explain what you don't understand about SMcGrew's answer then it sounds as though you are being unreasonably demanding, asking others to jump through hoops for your satisfaction.

Comment: @sammygerbill Again. I disagree. I do not think it is too much. But its interesting to note that everytime I keep giving reasons on why should an animation or graphic should be added I'm learning more (but not on the aspect which I intended). If the consensus here is that requesting an animation for a concept which for everyone is too simple and is too much or akin to jumping through hoops for my satisfaction then I'll have to keep trying by my own in other sources.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Steiner principle can be used to **show** that axis through the centre of mass has the lowest moment of inertia (across the parallel axes), but it doesn't explain **why**. First, the principle is not intuitive. Second, to prove it you would use a construction similar to what is needed to show the statement in the first place.

Here is my atempt to give intuition to the proof of the statement.

If we project everything to a plane perpendicular to the axes of interest, we basically want to find such a point $\vec y$, that sum of weighted squares
$$
I=\sum m_i(\vec x_i-\vec y)^2
$$
is minimal. This is a [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) problem.

Before showing this in general case, which can be overwhelming at first, let's consider a particular example of this problem in 1d case for two point masses $m_1$ and $m_2$:
$$
I=m_1(x_1-y)^2 + m_2(x_2-y)^2.
$$
Let's expand the squares and group as powers of $y$:
$$
I = (m_1+m_2)y^2 -2(m_1x_1+m_2x_2)y+(m_1x_1^2+m_2x_2^2).
$$

The plot of function $I(y)$ is a parabola. We can find the position of the parabola tip by completing the square:
$$
I=(m_1+m_2)\left(y^2-2\frac{m_1x_1+m_2x_2}{m_1+m_2}y+\left(\frac{m_1x_1+m_2x_2}{m_1+m_2}\right)^2\right)-\frac{\left(m_1x_1+m_2x_2\right)^2}{m_1+m_2}+(m_1x_1^2+m_2x_2^2) =\\
(m_1+m_2)\color{red}{\left(y-\frac{m_1x_1+m_2x_2}{m_1+m_2}\right)^2}+
\color{blue}{(m_1x_1^2+m_2x_2^2)-\frac{\left(m_1x_1+m_2x_2\right)^2}{m_1+m_2}}
$$
So now we see that $I$ contains two terms: blue one, that doesn't depend on $y$ and red one that depend on $y$ and cannot be negative. So the minimal value can be achieved when the red term is zero, which means that
$$
y=\frac{m_1x_1+m_2x_2}{m_1+m_2}.
$$

The case of 2d and arbitrary number of points doesn't change the procedure, it just makes the formulas scarier. The idea stays the same.
$$
I=\vec x^2\sum m_i - 2\vec x\cdot\left(\sum m_i\vec x_i\right)+\sum m_i\vec x_i^2 =\\
\left(\sum m_i\right)\left(\vec x^2-2\vec x\cdot\frac{\sum m_i\vec x_i}{\sum m_i}+\left(\frac{\sum m_i\vec x_i}{\sum m_i}\right)^2\right)-\frac{\left(\sum m_i\vec x_i\right)^2}{\sum m_i}+\sum m_i\vec x_i^2 = \\
\left(\sum m_i\right)\color{red}{\left(\vec x-\frac{\sum m_i\vec x_i}{\sum m_i}\right)^2}+
\color{blue}{\sum m_i\vec x_i^2-\frac{\left(\sum m_i\vec x_i\right)^2}{\sum m_i}}.
$$

Comment: It is a good explanation I think but it is lacking the part of how to prove this visually.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would explain it is non-rigorous, but intuitively clear: The moment of inertia $MI$ of a mass $M$ with respect to an axis is closely approximated by $ MI = M R^2$, where R is the perpendicular distance from the axis *to the center of mass of $M$*.  (This is very nearly true when the mass M occupies a small roughly spherical or cubical volume and R is fairly large; needs to be modified when M is close to the axis, but the result is roughly the same.)

When $R$ -> $0$, $MI$ obviously is minimized.  It doesn't reach zero unless $M$ is infinitely small.  You might be able to improve your intuitive feel for this if you model the $MI$ of two masses separated radially from an axis by different distances, then see how $MI$ changes as $R$ goes from a large distance to zero, and beyond to the other side of the axis.